# Can I replace the thermopile with a thermocouple in my water heater, and have it work properly?

Tags: water-heater, thermocouple

I'm having a tough time finding a thermopile at Home Depot, and lowes. I can find thermocouples all day long, and I can rig the wiring so I have no loose ends.  However, I know those two units don't generate the same amount of power. If I swap to the thermocouple, will I achieve "desired operation"?

Comment: Try a plumbing supply house rather than a Home Center? They will stock a wider range of stuff in their specialty, and be willing and able to special-order anything not in stock.

Answer (score 1):

If the thermocouple doesn't generate sufficient power, it won't function properly.  The replacement device has to produce enough power, to hold the circuit closed.

Answer (score 0):

A thermopile will generate more electricity than a thermocouple and usually has a different type of electrical connection. You should use a replacement with the same specifications as the original or your gas control may not function properly. You may find them labeled with names other than thermopile, like "pilot generator", "gas valve generator", "appliance pilot control" and stuff like that.